# GoogleMapReact is Defined but Never Used

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to display Google Map on my homestay app. I installed google map react on my cmd & there's a vulnerability message that I can't even fix with `npm audit fix --force`, so I decided to ignore it because I thought it's just a warning & my app still runs fine but when I imported googleMapReact on my project & then use it, suddenly there's an error that says googleMapReact is still not used which is strange because I already called it...

Here's my code:

```
import './App.css';
import Homestay from './homestays';
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import googleMapReact from 'google-map-react';

function App() {
  const [homes, homestays] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    fetch('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/algosigma/js-reactjs/master/homestays.json')
     .then(resp => resp.json())
     .then(data => homestays(data))
  });

  const center = {
    lat: -7.795424,
    lng: 110.371754
  }

  const home = homes.map((homestay) => {
    return <Homestay key={homestay.id} homestay={homestay} />
  });

  return (
    <div className="app">
      <div className="main">
        <div className="homestays">
          {home}
        </div>
      </div>
      <div className="map">
        <googleMapReact center={center} zoom={15}></googleMapReact>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

You will see that I already imported & used googleMapReact, but `'googleMapReact' is defined but never used` still appearing.

**Also one thing, there was another accident that I made when trying to fix this error by opening the cmd & type `npm audit fix --force` where I type it before changing my directory so I entered it on my Users folder :( Did that accident affects my folder & my projects inside it badly??**

Answer (score 0):

maybe try renaming the import starting with an uppercase such as `GoogleMapReact` instead of `googleMapReact`

Comment: I already did that before, all my contents are gone just blank white page. I originally wanted to type GoogleMapReact but the autocomplete message thing (idk what it's called) wanted me to type googleMapReact because GoogleMapReact (somehow) doesn't exist yet.

Comment: My first suspicion probably because what happened on the cmd